# Achieving ReactJS like functionality with plain JavaScript - no idea how to make the code less verbose

Tags: javascript, reactjs

As an exercise, I wanted to create a useEffect, useState functionality from React.

I achieved similar functionality but I don't like this part of the code:

```
function Comp() {
  let store = new Store();
  let [a, setA] = useState(10, store);
  let [b, setB] = useState(15, store);
```

Basically, each time I create a new "component" I need to create a store. Global store doesn't work because I would need to send additional data when setting new state value
( setValue(value, "KEY") ).

Is there a design pattern or something that I could use to achieve what React does? The only thing that comes to mind is writting sort of a transpiler, but it seems like an overkill and like I am missing something.

Link to the sandbox:

https://codesandbox.io/s/sweet-artem-wi2imw?file=/src/store.js

EDIT:

The question is how to avoid passing the store to each newly created component.

EDIT 2:

Functionality I want to achieve:

1. I create a "component"
2. Make use of the useState hook to get [ getter, setter ] =
   useState(value)
3. Each time a setter is called, the useEffect
   inside that component should be called, or more precisely it should
   check with store if it should be called.
4. There would be numerous
   components, calling setValue(value) from component A should not
   trigger a callback effect in component B (why global store doesn't
   work, unless i provide additional arguments on a setter to let the
   store know which callbacks it should run

Comment: What are the requirements you're trying to meet? React hooks are tightly coupled to the react component lifecycle; do you have something similar?

Comment: The functionality I want to achieve is that:

1. I create a "component"
2. Make use of the useState hook to get [ getter, setter ] = useState(value) 
3. Each time a setter is called, the useEffect inside that component should be called, or more precisely it should check with store if it should be called.
4. There would be numerous components, calling setValue(value) from component A should not trigger a callback effect in component B (why global store doesn't work, unless i provide additional arguments on a setter to let the store know which callbacks it should run

Comment: Without a component lifecycle, i don't think what you want can be done. React decides "ok, it's time to render instance 6 of component A, let me set up my internal state to match that" and then calls function A. Since it did all this setup work, if you call a hook while A is running, that hook knows which instance it is associated with. But if you're just calling `Comp()` without setting anything up ahead of time, i don't think react's patterns are going to work for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are sure not to write a transpiler yourself, try [decorator pattern](https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/decorator/typescript/example), but it only saves your time on `new Store`, you still need send it manually:

```js
// something like this:
@withNewStore
function Comp(store) {
  let [a, setA] = useState(10, store);
  let [b, setB] = useState(15, store);
```

However, if you are sure you only need `useState` and `useEffect`, you can do it more wildy:

```js
// something like this:
@withHooks
function Comp({useState,useEffect)) {
  let [a, setA] = useState(10);
  let [b, setB] = useState(15);
```

But keep in mind that the `decorator` spec is still on stage2 and will be likely to be changed in the future. It's not recommanded to use it in production.

More on this [decorators in typescript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/decorators.html)

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer! I didn't know that decorators could be used in plain JavaScript, I am aware that they exist in TypeScript but I assumed they use some non-standard syntax to achieve this.

This answer really makes the code much prettier and I will try implementing it later this day since it would be a good exercise as well, however I'm still wondering how React achieves what I want without any additional stuff.

Comment: @urth React didn't call function purey. It calls function with `fibers`, mounted with state and other context of the Component.

Comment: @urth I haven't spent much time on how typescipt achiveing decorator. You can see it on `ts playground` and try to implement it yourself! see : [a demo](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABMGAnAzlAFASkQbwFgAoRRCBdOAGwFMA6auAcywCIUNscAuZAQ2hxUAT0S0Abv2oh+UWgBM2OANwkyqWlBCokoSLASIsUfqmZa+-MCIA0iAA6o4D2qigiA0rRF9MqGDBmewVadAgAhyhhPgAFZ1d3EQARMIiYKOE8IlIyckoaBiZWDjRMXD4IaTolVXVEAF81Ygb1En1oeCR0WgowBVwCer6qOkYWdh6+gd4BIVFxKRk5RWVmjS0dPXBOoxMzCygrG3snFzcPb19Ef0DgxFDwyOjUOISLlLTnrKHcshHCuMSlMEDNKtVVnVck0SK1SCQINR+Oh0IgAKIAD34AFsHHQAMJIlG-MgAAU45Rw9VJIP6uHq2K0AAs4DMCHCGkA)

Answer (score 0):

I opted for the following solution, per @bbbbbbbboat suggestion

```
function decorate(fn) {
  let store = new Store();
  let props = {
    useEffect: useEffectBuilder(store),
    useState: useStateBuilder(store)
  };

  return fn(props);
}

function App() {
  decorate(Comp);
  decorate(Comp2);
}

function useStateBuilder(store) {
  return (value) => {
    return useState(value, store);
  };
}

function useEffectBuilder(store) {
  return (f, deps) => {
    return useEffect(store, f, deps);
  };
}
```

Usage:

```
  function Comp({useState,useEffect)) {
      let [a, setA] = useState(10);
      let [b, setB] = useState(15);
```